# Stating the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in simple terms

Tags: calculus

I went back and took first-semester calculus again order to refresh my skills. I never understood the relationship between the integral and the derivative when I first took calc many years ago.

In the middle of the course, the light bulb turned on, and I finally understood the relationship from a conceptual, or intuitive standpoint. In as few words as possible, this is the realization that finally occurred:

> The derivative of a function gives its rate of change at a given point. The integral of a function gives the area under the curve at a given point. The fundamental theorem merely says that the rate of change of the area under the curve is the value of the function at a given point.
>
> In other words, the derivative of the integral of a function is the function itself!

I realize this is no formal description. But is it comprehensible to someone who has a good conceptual understanding of calculus? Am I wrong in assuming that very few teachers have this conceptual understanding and attempt to relay it to their students?

Furthermore, might these concepts represent some kind of threat to an omnipresent orthodoxy of formalism? Could it be related to some difficulty with, or objection to, the concept of the infinitesimal?

Comment: Your description is a solid heuristic.  Unfortunately, it is hardly a novel way of thinking about the FOC.

Comment: @Dr. MV Thanks. I was afraid of that. LOL.

Comment: Of course this does not always hold.  If the function $f$ is not continuous, but the integral $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ exists in a neighborhood of $x$, it is possible that $\frac d{dx}\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ fails to exist.

Comment: @Dr. MV I don't consider discontinuous functions, or negative numbers for that matter, to apply to the real universe. :-)

Comment: Discontinuous functions occur frequently in physics.  And what do you mean negative numbers don't apply to the real universe?  If the charge of a proton is $q$, then what is the charge of an electron?  And what is subtraction then?

Comment: @Dr. MV Perhaps. I can't say. But the universe to me consists only of positive existences. Negative is meaningful in comparing positive existences.

Comment: http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/teaching-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-a-historical-reflection-newtons-proof-of-the-ftc

Comment: To answer your last few paragraphs, there are a large of number of teachers and book authors who are engaged in teaching calculus to students of age 16 years or so. Most of them don't have in depth knowledge of calculus. At least this is the situation in India. The reason is simple that most of the bright students don't make a career in school level teaching because of low income.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, intuition and informal reasoning don't present a threat to orthodox formalism. I especially favor informal reasoning which avoids excessive use of symbols and instead is presented in language of communication like English. The real problem here is not the informal, but rather non-rigorous arguments often given by crappy calculus textbooks and the student happily believes them.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. Your comments seem valid, but I consider my question to have been answered by Dr. MV's first comment.

Comment: Regarding such things as the existence of discontinuous functions and negative numbers, very few (if any) mathematical objects can truly be exhibited in the real world. Continuous functions (in the sense meant in differential calculus) have no more claim to real existence than discontinuous functions have. Even the set of positive integers is an abstraction. But these abstractions turn out to help us make useful predictions about the real world, whether or not the things they consist of literally exist.

Comment: @DavidK Well said. I realize there are problems in my thesis and certainly it was not stated rigorously. I still believe there is an inherent actuality to its assertions, however.

Comment: As for the main thesis of your question, I think you correctly identified the central ideas of calculus. It's unfortunate that your first calculus course did not make this clear and that the second one apparently obscured it as well. Maybe there is too much formalism in the standard first year calculus curriculum; certainly I did not find it a happy experience, and I _love_ math.

Comment: @DavidK Did you enjoy another math more than calc?

Comment: Actually I enjoyed real analysis, which I consider to be "third year calculus," much better than the first year. It wasn't the topic that was the problem, it was the curriculum.